# WCF. Bind request and response in custom encoder

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a wcf client and I need to log my requests and responses from external service.
I can do this in my custom message encoder, but I need some correlation Id to create files named like this: `id_request.xml` and `id_response.xml`.
So my question is how to pass some string from `ReadMessage` to `WriteMessage`?

I tried to use my implementation of `IClientMessageInspector` but WCF invokes `BeforeSendRequest` before encoding and message is incomplete. Also I can't save both request and response in `AfterReceiveReply` because it is possible that my application (or external service) will be crashed after I sent request but before response received.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution that works for me. In my implementation of `IClientMessageInspector` I created class `CorrelationObject`:

```
class CorrelationObject
{
  public string RequestFileName { get; set; }
  public string ResponseFileName { get; set; }
}
```

then in `BeforeSendRequest` I generate unique names with same Id as prefix and store that correlation object in request properties:

```
public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
{
  var id = Guid.NewGuid();
  var correlationObject = new CorrelationObject
  {
    RequestFileName = $"{id:N}_request.xml",
    ResponseFileName = $"{id:N}_response.xml"
  };
  request.Properties.Add("CorrelationObject", correlationObject);
  return correlationObject;
}
```

After that, WCF pass my request to message encoder

```
public override ArraySegment<byte> WriteMessage(Message message, 
  int maxMessageSize, BufferManager bufferManager, int messageOffset)
{
  // encoding and signing
  var encodedMessage = string.Empty;
  var correaltionObject = (CorrelationObject) message.Properties["CorrelationObject"];
  File.WriteAllText(correaltionObject.RequestFileName, encodedMessage);
}
```

At this point I saved my request. To save response, in message encoder I did following:

```
public override Message ReadMessage(ArraySegment<byte> buffer,
  BufferManager bufferManager, string contentType)
{
  var content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer.ToArray());
  var response = innerEncoder.ReadMessage(buffer, bufferManager, contentType);
  response.Properties.Add("RawMessage", content);

  // some other staff here..
}
```

And now WCF invokes `AfterReceiveReply` in my message inspector

```
public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
{
  var correlationObject = (CorrelationObject) correlationState;
  File.WriteAllText(correlationObject.ResponseFileName,
    reply.Properties["RawMessage"].ToString());
}
```

Now, both files are saved with the same prefix.